# apksigner, zipalign and jarsigner not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

I have created a Xamarin Form application using Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10 and archived the android application to APK file.

When I upload the APK to Google Play console to update my existing app, it says the APK is not signed. Then I used this command to sign the APK using the same certificate

`apksigner sign --ks <KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME> --ks-key-alias <ALIAS_NAME> <APK_FILE_NAME>`

When I try to upload the signed APK, it says the APK is not zipaligned. Then I used this command to zipalign

`zipalign -f -v 4 <OLD_APK_FILE_NAME> <NEW_APK_FILE_NAME>`

When I upload the zipaligned APK to console, it says the APK is not signed. After I sign using `apksigner` it says it is not zipaligned. I am keep on circulating in the same circle again and again.

Even after I zipalign the APK first and then sign, Same error messages are displaying again and again in same circle.

Even if I used **jarsigner**, the situation is same.

I followed the steps given here

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing/signing-the-app-package/manually-signing-the-apk/

But the APK not getting uploaded. What am I doing wrong?

Please note this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: `apksigner` requires you to `zipalign` prior. `jarsigner` requires you to `zipalign` after. These steps are automated by the [Archive Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/index?tabs=windows#archive-for-publishing) in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jon this is the correct answer, can you make it a top level answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Feel free to write up your own answer based off of what resolved your problem and accept it.

Comment: What is your Android SDK version? over or below v24.0.3?

Comment: @lemontree SDK version 27

Comment: @JonDouglas I tried in both the ways it did not work. Then I have deactivated the app and re-uploaded as new app, it is working but I lost all people installed the old app

Answer (score 3):

`apksigner` requires you to `zipalign` prior to signing. `jarsigner` requires you to `zipalign` after signing. This is [documented in the zipalign docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign).

Comment: If I use zipalign and then apksigner google play console tells me that apk is not zipaligned.

Comment: Like I say in the answer:
- either zipalign THEN apksigner, OR
- jarsigner THEN zipalign
The reverse orders won't work.